# How to interpret the output of git describe --contains

Tags: git

When I use `git describe --contains --match "v[0-9]*" <commitish> I get the following output

```
v4.0.0-beta3~1^2~58
```

How to interpret this? The `git describe` documentation doesn't give any hints. None of the examples use `--contains`. The tag is v4.0.0-beta3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those notations are batter documented in [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADv1510em) and [git-revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADv1510em), and refer to a ["side street" in graph walking](https://git.seveas.net/describing-the-relationship-between-commits.html#describing-the-relationship-between-commits)

[`git describe --contains`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe#Documentation/git-describe.txt---tags), instead of finding the tag that predates the commit, finds the tag that comes after the commit, and thus contains it.

Here, "the tag that comes after the commit" is one ancestor up, then take the second parent (because that ancestor is a merge commit), then take the 58th ancestor to get back to that commit.

```
  x--------------x----y
  |               \
v4.0.0-beta3.      z---z1--z2--...--z58 (= <commitish>)
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the "side street" link the most helpful for understanding. It also explains how to use `git rev-parse` to find the commit being referred to.